# Паюсная икра

Tags: значение-слов

Часто в отношении икры (по-моему, красной, но могу ошибаться) говорят "паюсная". Это выражение уже настолько на слуху,что как-то не задумываешься о его значении. Паюсная - и паюсная.
А что это такое? Что такое "паюсная" и что это за слово? Русское ли оно? И вся ли икра паюсная или есть разные виды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думается русское.  Кроме паюсной есть еще Ястык и ястычная икра.

Вот один из ответов.  http://otvet.mail.ru/question/19866124

А вот еще версия, вроде как официальная:  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%B8%F0%ED%E0%FF_%E8%EA%F0%E0

А вот есть такое.

Пояс

пояс по́яс род. п. -а, укр. по́яс, др.-русск., ст.-слав. поѩсъ ζώνή (Остром., Супр.), болг. по́яс, сербохорв. по̏jа̑с, па̑с, словен. роjа̑s, ра̑s, чеш., слвц. pás, польск. раs, в.-луж., н.-луж. раs. Праслав. *ро-jаsъ – обратное производное от ро-jаsаti; ср. русск. опоя́сать, от* jasati, откуда русск.-цслав. ɪасало "пояс" (Кирилл Иерусалимск., ХII в.; см. Срезн. III, 1665; Швицер, WuS 12, 32 и сл.). Далее сюда же лит. júostas "опоясанный", júosta "пояс", лтш. juôstа – то же, лит. júosti, júosmi (júosiu) "опоясывать", juosmuõ "бедра, пояс", лтш. juôzt "опоясывать", авест. уāstа- "опоясанный", уāh- ср. р. "пояс", греч. ζῶμα "пояс", ζώνη – то же, ζώννῡμι "опоясываю", ζωστός "опоясанный", алб. ngjesh "опоясываю" (см. Траутман, ВSW 108 и сл.; Педерсен, IF 5, 46; Бартоломэ 1291; Г. Майер, Alb. Wb. 308; М.–Э. 2, 127 и сл.. Мейе–Вайан 30; Гофман, Gr. Wb. 104. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Это сильно расходится с версией происхождения слова ястык от тюрок, декламируемая тем же Фасмером:
ястык ясты́к "что-либо целое, целый кусок", "целая икра одной рыбы", "мешочек, в котором заключена рыбья икра", поволжск., астрах. (Даль). Из тур., кыпч., крым.-тат., тат. jastyk "подушка" (Радлов 3, 223 и сл.). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973.

ЯСТЫ́К -а́ и -а; м. [тюрк. ястык] Рыб. Икра осетровых и частиковых рыб в плёнке, вынутая из рыбы; сама такая плёнка.
◁ Ясты́чный, -ая, -ое. Приготовленный в ястыке, полученный из ястыка. Я-ая икра.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998

В обоих способах приготовления икры используется мешок, один естественный, так сказать-плацебо, а второй просто пояс(паюсная, поясная, мешковая)--мешочек, куда набивают икру.

Причем ястык--это продавливание через сито, с удалением пленок.
Достал язык с икрой, тыкнул в сито.
Паюсная-- "Производят разделку икряной рыбы и пробивают ястыки через грохот.
Есть некоторая разница в современной технологии, которой раньше скорее всего не было.

Answer (score 3):

Паюсный. Икра, в которой икринки не отделены друг от друга, они спрессованные и слипшиеся (вернее сказать - "ссхошиеся"). Такая икра менее качественная, но гораздо лучше хранится и транспортируется. При использовании засола большого смысла в паюсном приготовлении нет, поэтому "паюсный" вариант икры остался только как более дешевый вариант зернистой, по сути на неё идет просто недозревшее "сырьё".

Значение слова несколько отошло от исходного "паюс" (мешочек в котором лежит икра у рыбы), восходящему к "юзъ" - однокоренному с "узел", "вязать".

Ястык. Это еще более дешевая (и еще менее "дозревшая") икра. Я думаю, что особых оснований не доверять Фасмеру нет. И значение, и этимология у него переданы верно. Сближение со славянскими корнями выглядит сомнительным. У фасмера про ястык ничего не сказано, у него (в гнезде "пояс") о другом корне говорит - "яс", "пояс". *Ястык* к тому очень трудно привязать.

Постановка вопроса о использовании этих названий только применительно к осетровой икре для меня оказалася несколько неожиданной. Не знаю. Традиционно - да, такие термины понятны по отношению именно к черной икре, но чтобы это было единственной возможной нормой... Совсем не уверен.

Ну конечно

"ГОСТ 18173-2004 Икра лососевая зернистая баночная. Технические условия"
http://vsegost.com/Catalog/40/4061.shtml

Вот "паюсная" в сочетании с "красной" мне не попадалась.
Но характерно, что ГОСТы используют полное название "икра паюсная осетровых рыб". Т.е. существование и другой, не от осетровых, все-таки предполагается.

Answer (score 2):

Есть зернистая – каждое зернышко легко отделяется одно от другого. А паюсная – это как бы такое однородное месиво.

Слова "зернистая" и "паюсная" относятся только к чёрной икре.

Comment: >Слова "зернистая" и "паюсная" относятся только к чёрной икре.  
  
Да вроде как нет...